# Woocommerce custom product loop no longer working after update

Tags: wordpress, loops, woocommerce, while-loop

I'm having an issue with a custom product loop for featured products. It worked fine before a update.

```
<?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                            'field'    => 'name',
                            'terms'    => 'featured',
                        ),
                    ),
                );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                global $product;

                $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
                $sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
                if($sale) {
                    echo '
                <div class="pickproductsitem">
                  <div class="pickprodimage" style="background-image: url(' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . ');"></div>
                  <div class="prodname">'.get_the_title().'</div>
                  <div class="prodinfo">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>
                  <div class="prodprice"><span style="text-decoration: line-through;">Only '.$currency.$price.'</span><span style="color: green;"> SALE '.$currency.$sale.'</span></div><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="prodbutton w-button">VIEW</a></div>';
                }
                elseif($price) 
                {
                    echo '
                <div class="pickproductsitem">
                  <div class="pickprodimage" style="background-image: url(' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . ');"></div>
                  <div class="prodname">'.get_the_title().'</div>
                  <div class="prodinfo">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>
                  <div class="prodprice">Only '.$currency.$price.'</div><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="prodbutton w-button">VIEW</a></div>';
                }

            endwhile;

            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
```

I've tried fixing the Permalinks but it hasn't sorted the issue. I'm no expert at Woo or even Wordpress but this loop did work.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display featured products then do use below code in your query args it will solve the issue.

```
<?php
            $meta_query   = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
            $meta_query[] = array(
                            'key'   => '_featured',
                            'value' => 'yes'
                            );
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'meta_query'  =>  $meta_query
                );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                global $product;

                $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
                $sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
                if($sale) {
                    echo '
                <div class="pickproductsitem">
                  <div class="pickprodimage" style="background-image: url(' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . ');"></div>
                  <div class="prodname">'.get_the_title().'</div>
                  <div class="prodinfo">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>
                  <div class="prodprice"><span style="text-decoration: line-through;">Only '.$currency.$price.'</span><span style="color: green;"> SALE '.$currency.$sale.'</span></div><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="prodbutton w-button">VIEW</a></div>';
                }
                elseif($price) 
                {
                    echo '
                <div class="pickproductsitem">
                  <div class="pickprodimage" style="background-image: url(' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . ');"></div>
                  <div class="prodname">'.get_the_title().'</div>
                  <div class="prodinfo">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>
                  <div class="prodprice">Only '.$currency.$price.'</div><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="prodbutton w-button">VIEW</a></div>';
                }

            endwhile;

            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
```

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work either. I've checked all of the settings for the products and none of them are hidden nor private. No Idea why its not working.

Comment: you want to display products which are `featured` right?

Comment: are you using paid theme or free one and which one as woocommerce 3.0 latest has some changes to store featured products

Comment: Yes, I want to display the Featured products. I'm using my own theme. Probably why its not working!